# thread pool executor accepting customqueue

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

Generally `ThreadPoolExecutor` accepts/access `Queue<Runnable>`. Is there any method that accepts/access a custom queue, i.e A queue of some object type `Queue<some class object>`?

Comment: You could implement Runnable in a class MyClass and then pass to it Queue<MyClass>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there aren't any method with your `CustomObject` in it's parameter.

`Runnable` is an interface.

You will actually pass a queue of your `CustomObject`s as a queue of `Runnable`.

You just have to make sure that your `CustomObject` implements the `Runnable` interface.